# How can i solve this problem about 215:Assertion failed?

Tags: python, opencv

When I finished the coding, `215:Assertion failed` happened, and I think there is no wrong code, but I couln't solve it. How could I solve this problem?

```
import urllib.request as req
url = "http://uta.pw/shodou/img/28/214.png"
req.urlretrieve(url, "test.png")

import cv2
img = cv2.imread("test.png")
print(img)

%matplotlib inline

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("test.jpg")
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.show()
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-0f580eb5ee11> in <module>
      6 import cv2
      7 img = cv2.imread("test.jpg")
----> 8 plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
      9 plt.show()

error: OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

Comment: `assert isinstance(img, type(None)), 'image not loaded' ` to check if the image is not None type. Meaning not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting above error because of below line:

```
img = cv2.imread("test.jpg")
```

Your image is actually a `PNG` file, not `JPG` file. So, replace above line to `img = cv2.imread("test.png")`.